# Editext not taking user typed value

Tags: android, list, android-edittext

In my app there is a Edit text and below there is a list with check box.When user selects a particular checkbox,that value is being displayed in the edittext.Now if user writes some values in the edittext and then selects the checkbox,then the value which user had typed is overridden by the selected value.I want both the values to be displayed in the edittext

Code

```
public class EmailListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<EmailModel> data;
    DbHandler dbHandler;
    int[] emails;
    static ArrayList<String> emailSeperated;
    private String strEmails, strTemp;

    public EmailListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EmailModel> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
        emails = new int[data.size()];
        emailSeperated = new ArrayList<String>();

    }

    @Override

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        dbHandler = new DbHandler(context);


        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.email_custom_list, viewGroup, false);
            holder.tvContact = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_email_name);
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_email_checkbox);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
//        if (emails[i] == 0) {
//            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
//        } else {
//            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
//        }


        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                                                       @Override
                                                       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                                                           if (compoundButton == holder.checkBox) {
                                                               if (b) {
                                                                   emails[i] = 1;
                                                                   //dbHandler.updateContactList(data.get(i).getUserID(), 1);


//

                                                               } else {

                                                                   emails[i] = 0;
                                                               }
                                                           }

                                                       }
                                                   }

        );

        holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (emails[i] == 1) {

                    emailSeperated.add(data.get(i).getEmail());
                    Log.e("Email values", emailSeperated.toString());
                    Log.e("Position", "" + i);


                } else if (emails[i] == 0) {

                    emailSeperated.remove(data.get(i).getEmail());
                    Log.e("Email values", emailSeperated.toString());
                    Log.e("Position", "" + i);
                }
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(ShareWithinpocketDocs.etEmailLists.getText().toString())) {

                    ShareWithinpocketDocs.etEmailLists.setText(ShareWithinpocketDocs.etEmailLists.getText().toString() + "," + emailSeperated.toString().subSequence(1, emailSeperated.toString().length() - 1));

                } else {
                    strTemp = emailSeperated.toString().substring(1, emailSeperated.toString().length() - 1);
                    Log.e("Email Seperated values", strTemp);
                    ShareWithinpocketDocs.etEmailLists.setText(strTemp);
                }
            }
        });


        if (emails[i] == 0) {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
//            emailSeperated.remove(data.get(i).getEmail());
//            Log.e("Email values", emailSeperated.toString());

//            ShareWithinpocketDocs.etEmailLists.setText(emailSeperated.toString());
        } else {
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
//            emailSeperated.add(data.get(i).getEmail());
//            Log.e("Email values", emailSeperated.toString());

        }


        holder.tvContact.setText(data.get(i).getEmail());


        return view;
    }


    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvContact;
        CheckBox checkBox;

    }
}
```

Comment: is `etEmailLists` is static ?

Comment: then, you have to test your case and tell me what you get, try to print `ShareWithinpocketDocs.etEmailLists.getText().toString()` just before the line you setText in, and tell me what's the result

Answer (score 0):

This will display what is currently in the EditText and the new text separated by a comma. Change

```
holder.tvContact.setText(data.get(i).getEmail());
```

to

```
String s = holder.tvContact.gettext().toString();
holder.setText(s + ", " + data.get(i).getEmail());
```

Comment: Man he is talking about the `EditText` not the `TextView`